# Insert bar in a plot and plot setting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to plot data like the following diagram with the bars as shown on the right side:
[image: example_img]

The current state of my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 450, xmax = 1000,
    ymin = 0.0, ymax = 0.6,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 0.1,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    % grid = both,
    % minor tick num = 1,
    % major grid style = {lightgray},
    % minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    width = 0.8 \textwidth,
    height = 0.3\textwidth,
    xlabel = {Wavelength [nm]},
    ylabel = {Reflectance [\%/100]}]

% Plot data from file
\addplot[color=blue, smooth, thick] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma]{figures-src/chapter2/reflectance_suger_beets.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

and it looks like as follows:
[image: reflectance_veg]

What i want to do is

1. insert the bars (e.g. the spectral bands red 632-692nm, red-edge etc.) into my plot,
2. add the axis on the top and on the right side, so that the diagram looks like is contained in a square like first figure (I'm not sure if I am formulating this in an understandable way or not...).

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    xmin = 450, xmax = 1000,
    ymin = 0.0, ymax = 0.6,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 0.1,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    width = 0.8 \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth,
    xlabel = {Wavelength [nm]},
    ylabel = {Reflectance [\%/100]}]

\fill[red!20!white] (axis cs:632,0.6) rectangle (axis cs:692,0);
\fill[red!40!white] (axis cs:706,0.6) rectangle (axis cs:746,0);
\fill[red!60!white] (axis cs:772,0.6) rectangle (axis cs:890,0);
\node[rotate=90] at (axis cs:662,0.3) {Red 632--692\,nm};
\node[rotate=90] at (axis cs:726,0.3) {Red-edge 706--746\,nm};
\node[rotate=90] at (axis cs:840,0.3) {NIR1 772--890\,nm};

\addplot[color=blue, smooth, thick, domain=450:1000] {0.001*(x-450)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! The bars are just perfect, however, the `axis on top` doesn't work for me, maybe you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work for me" means, please? Do you get errors or do you want to have a different visualization?

Comment: I did not get any error, but the axis are just like before without the top one and the one on the right side...

Comment: Actually, `axis on top` puts the axis lines and ticks on top of everything else. Without it, the colored bars would hide the axis ticks. Having axis lines at the top and right is the default in `pgfplots` and this default is not changed in my example. If you don't have top and right axis lines, then either you disable them somewhere else in your document or you use a buggy `tikz` setup, I think.

Comment: Also, if I compile the code in your original question, the result is different from the picture you posted. So there must be bugs or additional settings somewhere that you don't show.

Comment: Thanks, i found the problem! It was indeed disabled in my template :)